# I'm not earning Solstice

Tags: bug, winter-bash-2014

It's presently the 21st of December, and I've [left a few comments today](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/1204/doppelgreener?tab=activity&sort=comments) on RPG.SE.

That *seems* to suggest I should get [Solstice](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/solstice), which requires that I "post or comment on 12/21", but I'm not earning it. What's going on? Is there something I'm missing, or is the hat buggy?

Comment: You should have a hat on the way ;-)

Comment: @PeterJ I guess so! One of my comments got upvoted a few minutes ago. \o/ Hooray!

Comment: The automatically inserted dupe comment   earned me Solstice here. =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've noticed that the comments need to have an upvote before the hat is awarded.

Comment: It was this, I think! I just received my Solstice following one of my earlier comments being upvoted.

Comment: I think the description of the hat should be updated to avoid misunderstanding