# Accepted answer with no votes but no Naruto hat awarded?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2014

The *Naruto* hat is supposed to be issued for answering a question, getting marked as the accepted answer and then having no votes over a 12 hour period... like this, I guess?

[image: Answer 13 hours old, accepted, and the Naruto hat description with the line *no other votes for 12 hours* circled]

What am I missing?

Comment: And of course everyone goes and upvotes it... (look on the bright side, you now have [exactly 40k rep](http://i.stack.imgur.com/08uWt.png) :P)

Comment: As if you'd expect anything less around these parts, you can't leave such an obvious target out in the open!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 12 hours start when the *answer is accepted*. It was [accepted less than 4 hours](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/198128/timeline) before you posted your question here; you'll need to wait another 8 before the post is eligible.

Also, take into account that hats are awarded in batches, it can take up to a few hours to award.

Comment: Not sure where you get the "few hours" from, it shouldn't be much more than a few minutes after the hat conditions are fulfilled: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245922/how-often-do-the-new-hat-checks-get-run/245940#245940

Comment: @balpha conservative over-estimate? :-)